# How to get comments from videos using YouTube API v3 and Python?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-data-api

I've been trying to get comments (both threads and replies) from a given video on YouTube using Python (as an exercise to learn the language).

Based on the examples given at the official website (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list), I was able to get some of the comments, but not all of them.
I tried to add some code to deal with multiple pages, but I am having troubles to get the comments for videos with only a single page.

For example, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gd_L7DVKTA8 has 17 comments (including replies), but I'm only able to obtain 7 threads and 2 replies. Interestingly, I get the same results (only 7 threads) using the API Explorer available at the link above.

My code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Usage:
# python scraper.py --videoid='<video_id>'

from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.tools import argparser
from apiclient.discovery import build

YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"
DEVELOPER_KEY = 'key'


def get_comment_threads(youtube, video_id, comments):
   threads = []
   results = youtube.commentThreads().list(
     part="snippet",
     videoId=video_id,
     textFormat="plainText",
   ).execute()

  #Get the first set of comments
  for item in results["items"]:
    threads.append(item)
    comment = item["snippet"]["topLevelComment"]
    text = comment["snippet"]["textDisplay"]
    comments.append(text)

  #Keep getting comments from the following pages
  while ("nextPageToken" in results):
    results = youtube.commentThreads().list(
      part="snippet",
      videoId=video_id,
      pageToken=results["nextPageToken"],
      textFormat="plainText",
    ).execute()
    for item in results["items"]:
      threads.append(item)
      comment = item["snippet"]["topLevelComment"]
      text = comment["snippet"]["textDisplay"]
      comments.append(text)

  print "Total threads: %d" % len(threads)

  return threads


def get_comments(youtube, parent_id, comments):
  results = youtube.comments().list(
    part="snippet",
    parentId=parent_id,
    textFormat="plainText"
  ).execute()

  for item in results["items"]:
    text = item["snippet"]["textDisplay"]
    comments.append(text)

  return results["items"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
  argparser.add_argument("--videoid", help="Required; ID for video for which the comment will be inserted.")
  args = argparser.parse_args()
  youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

  try:
    output_file = open("output.txt", "w")
    comments = []
    video_comment_threads = get_comment_threads(youtube, args.videoid, comments)

    for thread in video_comment_threads:
      get_comments(youtube, thread["id"], comments)

    for comment in comments:
      output_file.write(comment.encode("utf-8") + "\n")

    output_file.close()
    print "Total comments: %d" % len(comments)

  except HttpError, e:
    print "An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content)
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 4):

Im using this code

```
import os
import pickle
import google.oauth2.credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json" # for more information  to create your credentials json please visit https://python.gotrained.com/youtube-api-extracting-comments/
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl']
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube'
API_VERSION = 'v3'

def get_authenticated_service():
    credentials = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            credentials = pickle.load(token)
    #  Check if the credentials are invalid or do not exist
    if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
        # Check if the credentials have expired
        if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
            credentials.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
            credentials = flow.run_console()

        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(credentials, token)

    return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials = credentials)

def get_video_comments(service, **kwargs):
    comments = []
    results = service.commentThreads().list(**kwargs).execute()
    while results:
        for item in results['items']:
            comment = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textDisplay']
            comments.append(comment)
        # Check if another page exists
        if 'nextPageToken' in results:
            kwargs['pageToken'] = results['nextPageToken']
            results = service.commentThreads().list(**kwargs).execute()
        else:
            break

    return comments


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # When running locally, disable OAuthlib's HTTPs verification. When
    # running in production *do not* leave this option enabled.
    os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
    service = get_authenticated_service()
    videoId = input('Enter Video id : ') # video id here (the video id of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vedLpKXzZqE -> is vedLpKXzZqE)
    comments = get_video_comments(service, part='snippet', videoId=videoId, textFormat='plainText')

print(len(comments),comments)
```

good luck

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch all the comments using the nextPageToken. YouTube v3 API has gone something messy. But don't worry, i think this is something you are looking for.

```
YOUTUBE_COMMENT_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads'
def get_video_comment(self):

    def load_comments(self):
        for item in mat["items"]:
            comment = item["snippet"]["topLevelComment"]
            author = comment["snippet"]["authorDisplayName"]
            text = comment["snippet"]["textDisplay"]
            print("Comment by {}: {}".format(author, text))
            if 'replies' in item.keys():
                for reply in item['replies']['comments']:
                    rauthor = reply['snippet']['authorDisplayName']
                    rtext = reply["snippet"]["textDisplay"]

                print("\n\tReply by {}: {}".format(rauthor, rtext), "\n")

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    mxRes = 20
    vid = str()
    parser.add_argument("--c", help="calls comment function by keyword function", action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument("--max", help="number of comments to return")
    parser.add_argument("--videourl", help="Required URL for which comments to return")
    parser.add_argument("--key", help="Required API key")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if not args.max:
        args.max = mxRes

    if not args.videourl:
        exit("Please specify video URL using the --videourl=parameter.")

    if not args.key:
        exit("Please specify API key using the --key=parameter.")

    try:
        video_id = urlparse(str(args.videourl))
        q = parse_qs(video_id.query)
        vid = q["v"][0]

    except:
        print("Invalid YouTube URL")

    parms = {
                'part': 'snippet,replies',
                'maxResults': args.max,
                'videoId': vid,
                'key': args.key
            }

    try:

        matches = self.openURL(YOUTUBE_COMMENT_URL, parms)
        i = 2
        mat = json.loads(matches)
        nextPageToken = mat.get("nextPageToken")
        print("\nPage : 1")
        print("------------------------------------------------------------------")
        load_comments(self)

        while nextPageToken:
            parms.update({'pageToken': nextPageToken})
            matches = self.openURL(YOUTUBE_COMMENT_URL, parms)
            mat = json.loads(matches)
            nextPageToken = mat.get("nextPageToken")
            print("\nPage : ", i)
            print("------------------------------------------------------------------")

            load_comments(self)

            i += 1
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("User Aborted the Operation")

    except:
        print("Cannot Open URL or Fetch comments at a moment")
```

Find the full source code for other utilites at [GitHub](https://github.com/srcecde/python-youtube-api)

This script can fetch comments (along with replies), perform search and return videos, channels and playlist in categorized form and also returns country based search results.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here it is. I have added. If this finds to be useful, accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, the script you provided still doesn't do what I'm trying to achieve. For example, the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gd_L7DVKTA8 has 33 comments, but the script only finds 18. This 18 is actually the number of threads (the higher level comments), but it doesn't include the replies as well (which YouTube also calls "comments"). And that is actually the problem here, because the script I posted in the question can find the threads correctly, but some comments are not being reached.

Comment: @mshcruz Now, it can fetch comments along with replies. Please refer the updated code. I have also pushed the update on [GitHub] (https://github.com/srcecde/python-youtube-api). Please accept the answer if this helps.

Comment: @SrceCde: Thanks for updating the answer and the code. Although it now gets some replies, it still does not get all of them. If you check the comments for the video I posted (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gd_L7DVKTA8), you can see that the most voted comment is "Excellent album! Greetings from Venezuela. " followed by 4 replies. However, the script you provided only returns the first reply ("Support the band... Buy the album :)"), but not the others. So in the end, it only gets 25 comments (threads+replies) instead of the 33 it shows in the YouTube page.

Comment: Trying your code in 2018, but it always gives the error "Cannot Open URL or Fetch comments at a moment".

Comment: @YanKingYin Can you double check the parameters that you are passing while running the file. Or can you paste the command here.
For Ref: `python3 youtube_api_cmd.py --sc --channelid AXelk6aHijZq-GJBBB9YpReA --key AIzaS************Q`
ChannelID, I have mentioned here is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you are dealing with the same problem i had. 
Comments your are missing most proabably are hidden behind a comment Thread.
Simple solution, after you getting all comment threads id, take each comment thread id and check whether it has hidden comments, if so scrape them. Here is the simple example:

```
if (item['snippet']['totalReplyCount']>0):
            res2 = comments_list(youtube, 'snippet', item['id'])
            for item2 in res2['items']:
                commentL = list()
                commentL.append(item2['id'])
                commentL.append(item2['snippet']['authorChannelUrl'])

def comments_list(service, part, parent_id):
    results = service.comments().list(
    parentId=parent_id,
    part=part
  ).execute()

    return results
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I cannot understand your suggestion. I am checking the 'hidden' comments inside threads with my **get_comments** function (it has basically the same code you provided).

Comment: By the way, trying the code with the video I mentioned in the question now works (15 threads and 25 comments), but it does not work for this one (among others): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kTentrFO7Q
The video has 487 comments, but the code only finds 417.

Comment: Hey mate, that is a strange case, as i got same numbers. I went through one third of comments of your given video (was too lazy to check all of them), and compared them side by side with what has been captured with API. Nothing actually was missing. Maybe Google really doesn't show downvoted comments, or maybe users deleted their comments but that doesn't impact the overall score.

Comment: First, I want to thank both of you for this. I think I found your issue: in ``youtube.commentThreads().list()``, there is an optional parameter that sets the maximum number of replies returned to 20. Unfortunately, the maximum allowed is 100, but if you include ``maxResults=100`` in these function calls, you'll get most of the total comments. So, in the listed video, I suspect that there are a few threads which exceed 20 comments.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of the API, you can only get replies to top level comments. Further replies that are not replying to the top level comments can't be fetched.
Source - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list

This contributes to a significant reduction in the number of comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the same root cause, but I ran into trouble recently when I was trying to access all comments of a video. I would get a list of comment threads, but when I tried to find all the replies to those comments: some comments would show up and some wouldn't. I noticed, however, that the API query you can try out in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list) would usually seem to retrieve more results than attempts I made in my own code. I checked the Network panel and noticed that the example in the API documentation is making calls to https://content.googleapis.com - not https://www.googleapis.com as it instructs others to do. I had better luck using the `content` URL instead, but I'm not sure why there is such a discrepancy between the two.