# Scrape chat from other user's YouTube Livestream

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I have a program to scrape (almost) all of the comments from a given YouTube video from [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606055/how-to-get-comments-from-videos-using-youtube-api-v3-and-python), and I am looking to do the same thing for the chat in a livestream. From what I understand, I need to get the `liveChatId`, and I need to do that with the `liveBroadcast` function. Additionally, I need to use an OAuth2 key, as opposed to a regular developer key, which I use for the program to get comments from videos. However, I haven't seen a way to get the comments from an arbitrary user's livestream, only my own, and I'd like to get the comments from any livestream I want. Specifically, I'd like to know if this is possible, and if so, what I would need to do to accomplish this.

Comment: We are not the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/).

Comment: @MattClark yes, I went through the API yesterday, and I was unable to piece together a solution to what I want. I've been going off of https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams/list#try-it and https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list#try-it Now, when ``list_streams(youtube)`` is called, I get a "The user is not enabled for live streaming." error. I suppose that I am only getting my account info back from this function call. So, it's not clear to me if I can get an arbitrary stream, or how I'd go about it if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting `The user is not enabled for live streaming` is because your account isn't enabled for live streaming. The Live Streaming API will only return results from your own account as far as I can tell.