# Using Python and YouTube API to get all comment and replies

Tags: python, pandas, youtube-api

I'm hoping someone can help me solve this problem and if not, tell me why it doesn't work. I'm trying to get all comments and replies from a YouTube video for practice. I hope to then be able to expand upon the code to do sentiment and network analysis for entire channels. The problem is that the code I have written doesn't appear to get all the replies and I'm unsure if it even gets all the comments. Similar issues were discussed in [How to get comments from videos using YouTube API v3 and Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606055/how-to-get-comments-from-videos-using-youtube-api-v3-and-python) without a solution given.

```
def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    DEVELOPER_KEY = "yourapikey" #<--- insert API key here

    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, developerKey = DEVELOPER_KEY)

    request = youtube.commentThreads().list(
        part="snippet, replies",
        order="time",
        maxResults=100,
        textFormat="plainText",
        videoId="aCjyqziVSMA"
    )
    
    response = request.execute()
    full = pd.json_normalize(response, record_path=['items'])
    while response:
        
        if 'nextPageToken' in response:
            response = youtube.commentThreads().list(
                part="snippet",
                maxResults=100,
                textFormat='plainText',
                order='time',
                videoId='aCjyqziVSMA',
                pageToken=response['nextPageToken']
            ).execute()
            
            df2 = pd.json_normalize(response, record_path=['items'])
            full = full.append(df2)
            
        else:
            break
    return full
```

After running the function above I can break down the replies to comments using this block of code. For simplicity, I only took the first instance of where a comment has a reply

```
df2 = test[test['snippet.totalReplyCount']>0].reset_index(drop=True)
pd.json_normalize(df2['replies.comments'][0])
```

As you can see, the first result with replies only grabbed 4 of the 166 possible

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is this a limitation for the API call itself?

**Edit 1**

It seems that another method to do it would be to (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads):

> To retrieve all of the replies for the top-level comment, you need to call the comments.list method and use the parentId request parameter to identify the comment for which you want to retrieve replies.

However, I'm not very good with API calls yet and I do not know how to make the specific call. If someone gives me the method to do that and it works, I'll accept that as the answer as well :)

**Edit 2 (2022-05-23)**

Here is the solution I came up with. This function will grab all the replies it can from each comment using Google api and put it into a dataframe. You can then join this data frame onto the original comments data frame to get every reply and every comment (assuming you don't run out of credits)

```
# function
def repliesto(parentId):
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    DEVELOPER_KEY = DevKey #your dev key

    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, developerKey = DEVELOPER_KEY)

    request = youtube.comments().list(
        part="snippet",
        maxResults=100,
        parentId=parentId,
        textFormat="plainText"
    )
    response = request.execute()

    replies = pd.json_normalize(response, record_path=['items'])
    while response:

        if 'nextPageToken' in response:
            response = youtube.comments().list(
                part="snippet",
                maxResults=100,
                parentId=parentId,
                textFormat="plainText",
                pageToken=response['nextPageToken']                
            ).execute()

            df2 = pd.json_normalize(response, record_path=['items'])
            replies = pd.concat([replies, df2], sort=False)

        else:
            break
    return replies

# get the top-level comment id from each reply author. full is 
what I called the data frame that contains the comments

replyto = []
for reply in full[(full['snippet.totalReplyCount']>0)] 
['snippet.topLevelComment.id']:
    replyto.append(reply)

# create a empty dataframe to contain the all the replies and use a for 
loop to place each item in our replyto list into the function defined 
above

replies = pd.DataFrame()
for reply in replyto:
    df = repliesto(reply)
    replies = pd.concat([replies, df], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: This is the answer to your question: [YouTube Data API to crawl all comments and replies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64276640/8327971).

Comment: Thank you @stvar. I've looked over the response and it looks like it will work. Late last night I also figured out a way to do it and this fully explains why I need to do it the way I found :D I'll post my full answer for others :)

Comment: DataStraine - where is your answer for others? ;-)

Comment: @Simone

I thought I responded or edited. Please see my edit above that I just made

Comment: As of this code, google api didn't support nested replies so you could only get the comment and all the direct replies to that comment from it.

Comment: Please note that if your latest edit is an answer to the question, you should really post it as an answer!

Comment: I would, but it won't let anyone reply and it doesn't reopen the question when I edit it.